# How to print a vector layer over Google map? "Physical Printing" 

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, geoext, printing, ext-js

I use Geoserver, Openlayers, Extjs and GeoExt to build an app.

I am trying to get vector layer on Google map printed with pop up a Print dialog, I tried :

```
var targetElement = Ext.getCmp('mapPanel');
                    var myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=600,height=500');
                    myWindow.document.write('<html><head>');
                    myWindow.document.write('<title>' + 'Title' + '</title>');
                    myWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
                    myWindow.document.write(targetElement.body.dom.innerHTML);
                    myWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
                    myWindow.print();
```

it works fine except that Vector layer were not printed. I got Google map only. How I can do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Is your vector layer in the Google Mercator projection (900913)?  I believe your vector layer has to be in the same coordinate system as the Google Map tiles.

Comment: Yes I use the new Google projection and transform vector layer using: `.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"))` ... it displayed on the map but when I print it on real paper I got Google layer only.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers will require you enable the “Print background colors and images” in order to print properly.

Did you tried with different browsers?

Comment: Thanks! it works in Firefox but not in Chrome. How I could fix it ?

Comment: Also, the popup of vector feature was not printed! though all features printed just fine.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984824/chrome-wont-print-custom-google-map-that-is-inside-a-div                       and you can also try to play with Google Chrome hidden options - at the adress bar just type chrome://about/ and play with it (start with chrome://flags/)

Comment: And plus this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392366/print-background-colours-in-chrome?rq=1                                       But may be not possible to do it on Google Chrome...